# How to use QGIS as a service?

Tags: qgis

Can I use QGIS in my application? Is there any plugin or connector any service there through which I will connect with my application? Please assist me.

Comment: Please read How to Ask and write a clear problem description. 
Also, show some of your efforts.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: From what kind of app you want connect? Use a batch start e.g. with VB.net like `Process.Start("C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\bin\qgis-ltr.bat")`